# Yellow or crossed onion? How can I see that a Tor connection is secure or broken?

Tags: security

In Vidalia, a yellow onion or a gray onion indicated a problem or the end of a Tor connection. How can I follow this in Tor Browser 3.6.2?

Is the green onion eventually turning to yellow or does it somehow indicate an abnormal end of the connection to the Tor circuit?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much. In the meantime I've also seen that the symbol can eventually turn to grey or then surfing turns impossible at all, if Tor is broken.
However as I also miss some other informations about the connection (number of active nodes for my connection and the world map) I followed a description somewhere in the forum and installed in addition to TBB 3.6.2 also a simplified vidalia package.
Works fine now, both cooperate well.

Answer (score 0):

Basically in the tor Browser bundle it automatically configures the connection so that you don't need to worry about any advanced settings  thereby leaving your connection secure(the browser showing the green onion on successful configuration).

In case the connection is insecure or broken you will know about it under the notification area or the connection display where you start tor(clicking on the play  button)